# Invalid parameter error while trying to add policy in SNS topic

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to configure SNS to automate Snowpipe using SQS notifications. As per the snowflake document, I am adding the below policy(mark in bold) to the existing SNS topic access policy.  but it's not accepting. I am getting an error.  Any clue what is wrong here?

> (Couldn't set topic access policy.
> Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting the attribute access policy. Invalid parameter: Policy Error: null)

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
        {
             **"Sid":"1",
             "Effect":"Allow",
             "Principal":{
                        "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/sns”-topic-iam-arn
                      },
             "Action":[
                        "sns:Subscribe"
                     ],
             "Resource":[
                         "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:9876543210:s3_bucket”
                        ]**
     }, 
      
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": " "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:9876543210:s3_bucket",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": “99988877760”
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:*:*:s3_bucket_name"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is same error as yours. Would you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57537475/cloudformation-cannot-create-policy-for-sns-topic-on-aws-using-serveless-framew

Comment: in my josn dictionary, format was wrong, i added subscription action in between two statement. i reorder and it got it fixed.

Comment: can you close this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use this bucket policy and change the ARN of buckek and SNS

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
            "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
            "SNS:AddPermission",
            "SNS:RemovePermission",
            "SNS:DeleteTopic",
            "SNS:Subscribe",
            "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
            "SNS:Publish"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:721702575972:topic1",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "AWS:SourceOwner": "721702575972"
            },
            "ArnLike": {
                "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::mlpoiuy"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```